# What is the fastest way to memset() a GPU buffer with OpenCL?

Tags: performance, opencl, memset

I'm using OpenCL, and I need to `memset()` some array in global device memory. CUDA has a `memset()`-like API function, but OpenCL does not. I read [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/458763/memset/), where I found two possible alternatives:

1. using `memset()` on the host with some scratch buffer, then `clEnqueueWriteBuffer()` to copy that to the buffer on the device.
2. Enqueueing the following kernel:

   ```
   __kernel void memset_uint4(
       __global  uint4* mem,
       __private uint4  val) 
   {
       mem[get_global_id(0)] = val; 
   }
   ```

Which is better? Or rather, under which circumstances/for which platforms is one better than the other?

**Note:** If the special case of zero'ing memory merits special treatment, that would be nice to know too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`clEnqueueFillBuffer()`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueFillBuffer.html) from OpenCL v1.2. That is exactly what you need. And it is very flexible on how to fill the buffer with patterns.

If you are on 1.1 or below.... then you have to resort to other approaches.

Comment: Since the OP mentioned CUDA, it's likely they're working with a card from NVidia, on which currently only OpenCL 1.1 is supported. Also your answer doesn't address the question of which of the two given methods is "better".

Comment: NVIDIA cards with the Kepler or later architecture support OpenCL 1.2 since sometime in 2015. [Driver release notes](https://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/10/10/us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/350.12/350.12-win8-win7-winvista-desktop-release-notes.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

A great way to do this very fast (if you have extra memory available) is to have a pre-sized initialized array (such as one filled with all zeros) and then do an on device copy any time you need to zero out the buffer. In my experience this was much faster than any of the calls to fill in OpenCL or CUDA. Obviously this is a special case but much faster when I last tested it.

Comment: Was it specifically faster than clEnqueueFillBuffer?

Comment: @einpoklum I made a test and enqueueCopyBuffer is faster than enqueueFillBuffer, only just though in 10k tries:  fillBuffer gets: 00.000059, copyBuffer gets:  00.000048

Comment: @Jonno_FTW: Is that in seconds? Also, for what memory size? If you have the test up-and-running (I'm not working on OpenCL stuff right now), perhaps run it with, say, 1 GB at a time; that should give you longer execution times per run for a comparison. Also, the zero case could be different than the case of other values.

Comment: Alright, I tried again using 64 million unsigned ints on my AMD R9 380, code is here: https://gist.github.com/JonnoFTW/2aa358e7b7e57eecf140ce7beae3fa85
Winner was enqueue fill buffer about twice as fast.