# OpenCL: How to create initialized device-side buffer

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm currently creating a kernel that smooths out a 3D volume from a source buffer onto a destination buffer using calls such as:

```
    d_aVolumeInput  = clCreateBuffer(g_dGpuContext, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,    _nVoxelsScanArea, _aVolumeInput,    &g_nErrNum);    CHECK_OCL();
    d_aVolumeSmooth = clCreateBuffer(g_dGpuContext, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY| CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,    _nVoxelsScanArea, _aVolumeInput,    &g_nErrNum);    CHECK_OCL();
```

Unfortunately, it is much more efficient for my kernel to assume an initialized destination array 'd_aVolumeSmooth' and so far the only way I've found to make it work it to also send my _aVolumeInput' to both arrays, causing several extra megabytes of data to be sent each frame...

Is there a way for me to allocate a device-side memory of the right size and have it zero-initialized?

Comment: Perhaps http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueFillBuffer.html

Comment: If you want to support OpenCL version 1.0, you won't have `clEnqueueFillBuffer` available. But you can easily write an equivalent kernel implementing the exact same behavior.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100948/what-is-are-the-fastest-memset-alternatives-for-opencl

Comment: Oh thanks guys!  When looking for this I was scouring in header files looking for things like 'zero' and 'clear' but 'fill' didn't come to mind... This will save a bunch of time per frame... will do right now and report! ;)

Comment: Bummer!  My NVidia card only supports OpenCL 1.1 and there is no clEnqueueFillBuffer!  What a huge omission!  (Am looking at fast & easy way to init my buffer...)

Comment: For OpenCL 1.1 just write a kernel that inits the buffer; it will still be faster than uploading an empty buffer.