# memset local variable/memory in OpenCL

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I am porting existing Reed-Solomon decoding code to OpenCL
There are some local arrays in my kernel, like uint myarray[256]; in local functions.
And I have quite a number of memset functions over them and I've failed to use them.
I can just write filling them in a loop, but that might be inefficient. Also, some suggestions about writing such a loop are welcome too, cause seems OpenCL just don't have memset.

But OpenCL complains about missing memset the way it seems not being missing it entirely

> warning: implicitly declaring C library function 'memset' with type
>   'void *(void *, int, unsigned long)'

and suggests to include `<string.h>` but fails to find it

> `fatal error: <string.h> file not found.`

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete and verifiable example ([mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Well, take the simpliest OpenCL example from the OpenCL SDK and write something like
uint myarray[256];
memset(myarray, 0, 100);
at, say, the beginning of the kernel source.

Comment: did you `#include <string.h>` in your code?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and wrote what error it produces (file not found). Are there standard headers for OpenCL and how do I include them? Hmm, I've not googled this that way...

Comment: Thanks! I'll stick to loop filling then. This is actually the answer =\

Comment: what about this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100948/what-is-are-the-fastest-memset-alternatives-for-opencl

Comment: I've seen this. I don't have one large amount of data that needs to be filled. I only have several arrays in local functions of size less than 256. And they need to be filled in the middle of the execution sometimes, so I cannot really see how out of kernel enqueuing can help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no memset (nor any of the rest of the C standard library) available in OpenCL device code, so you'll need to either loop manually (possibly with a `#pragma unroll` hint) or, if the array is actually `local` in the OpenCL sense (i.e. shared between work-items in a work-group) have each work-item clear one of the elements (which is considerably more efficient).